# In R: grab all alnum characters before the first punctuation

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector `s` of strings (or NAs), and would like to get a vector of same length of everything before first occurrence of punctionation (`.`).

```
s <- c("ABC1.2", "22A.2", NA)
```

I would like a result like:

```
[1] "ABC1" "22A"  NA
```

Comment: You can remove everything after and including the `.` with `sub("\\..*", "", s)`

Comment: Any punctuation or just `.`?

Comment: Smart, I was focusing on extracting and not removing.

Comment: @ stribizhev : just `. ` (sorry for being unclear on that)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove all symbols (incl. a newline) from the first dot with the following Perl-like regex:

```
s <- c("ABC1.2", "22A.2", NA)
gsub("[.][\\s\\S]*$", "", s, perl=T)
## => [1] "ABC1" "22A"  NA
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/8OZ9Iw)

The regex matches

- `[.]` - a literal dot
- `[\\s\\S]*` - any symbols incl. a newline
- `$` - end of string.

All matched strings are removed from the input with `""`. As the regex engine analyzes the string from left to right, the first dot is matched with `\\.`, and the  greedy `*` quantifier with `[\\s\\S]` will match all up to the end of string.

If there are no newlines, a simpler regex will do: `[.].*$`:

```
gsub("[.].*$", "", s)
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/Pqrfeu)